# How to programmatically force select 2G or 3G in iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I want to know is there any iOS API or trick [Which can be used for enterprise edition of the app. I guess apple will allow enterprise apps to write tricks] allow us to force select 2G or 3G for iPhone.

Version am targeting is iOS 8.0.2

I have tried using `SCNetworkReachability` and [Reach ability sample app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple but it is not fitting to my need. During my search i found [this](http://www.numbweb.com/2014/07/17/switch-2g-3g-iphone-ir0setool/101/) app is doing the same. So there will be a way to achieve it. But i cant able to find the correct API.

Comment: if this is not the right place to ask this question please let know in comments before changing the question to hold. In that case i can remove it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You cannot do this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My doubt is how come that app is working? So i thought there will be some trick.

Comment: You are almost certainly looking at malware or something that requires the iPhone be hacked.